# How to access other record fields inside grid's widgetcolumn in Extjs6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a grid with a progressbar widget column:

```
{
    xtype    : 'widgetcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'progress',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'progressbarwidget',
        textTpl: [
            '{percent:number("0")}% done'
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I change `textTpl` to be something like `{record.data.field1} out of {record.data.field2}`, it seems that only current column value is being accessible.

See http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#widget-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look into the `progressbarwidget` code, your fear is well founded.

```
updateValue: function(value, oldValue) {
    ...
    if (textTpl) {
        me.setText(textTpl.apply({
            value: value,
            percent: Math.round(value * 100)
        }));
    }
```

You would have to extend that class, override the `updateValue` function, and use something like this:

```
me.setText(textTpl.apply({
    value: value,
    percent: Math.round(value * 100),
    record: me.$widgetRecord
}));
```

and there you go.